How can I connect to SQL Server over a secure connection from Delphi 2007?
I have come across an issue with a Delphi 2007 application that I work with. We use ADOConnection and ADOQueries, but we currently have to start using TLS 2.0 and there`s no compatibility.
We are using SQLOLEDB and SqlServer.
What I have done so far is:

I have tried UniDAC`s TUniConnection, as I read it was both TLS 2.0 and ADOQuery compatible, but I started a new project to test it and ADOQuery does not identify it as an available connection

I have also downloaded a Secure Bridge's package hoping I would be able to use its TMSConnection component, but after installing it, the component is not available in Delphi 2007 for me. I wonder if it's because it's a trial version?


How can I make Delphi 2007's ADOConnection 2.0 compatible?
Do I need to start using MSOLEDBSQ instead of SQLOLEDB?

Assuming TLS means Transport Layer Security. Did you mean TLS 1.2? The latest version of TLS is 1.3. Besides that though, your question is off-topic for [so] as you're asking us to provide you with suggestions.

You might want to edit/rephrase the question to something that can be objectively answered, instead of asking for suggestions. Something more like "How can I connect to SQL Server over a secure connection from Delphi 2007?"

You will have to change the body of your question too to reflect the title. It still contains the "I would like to ask if there's any components available..."

Even changing to "how can I..." doesn't really help: you really need to edit your question to show your work (a [mcve]) and be specific in your question. Right now, you've only given a high level description of what you tried. Please read [ask] and then edit accordingly.

Related: VB6 application ado connection for TLS1.2. It is asking for VB, but you should be able to apply it to Delphi too, as you just have to adjust your connection string.
